# Python 3 error with Tkinter: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-padding"

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been learning tkinter with the help of a python book. However, the python book is written for python 2 and I'm using python 3. This has generated several errors, and up to now I've been able to fix them, with the aid of other questions here. It is a basic program that shows a window with buttons to play 3 games or to destroy the window. When either of the first two games(rock paper scissors and hangman) are opened, they are supposed to open a Toplevel() that has various buttons that lets you play the game. I haven't written the graphics code for the third game yet. They don't play, though, because of an error: **_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-padding"**
which I haven't found any detail about online. I understand that the unknown option means that that attribute/keyword doesn't exist in my version of tkinter and python 3.
The error lines look like:
**rpsFrame = Frame(rpsWindow, padding = '3 3 12 12', width = 300)**

In case you need it, the error and code are below.
(this code doesn't run without additional code)
(if you want this code I will add it, but I want to keep this shortish)

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python Book\Graphics\Hangman.py", line 149, in gui
    hmFrame = Frame(hmWindow, padding = "3 3 12 12", width = 300)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2582, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2122, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-padding"
```

Here is the interface code:

```
from tkinter import *
import RockPaperScissors
import Hangman
import PokerDice

root = Tk()
root.title("Linux User & Developer's Mega Games Collection")

mainframe = Frame(root, height = 200, width = 500)
mainframe.pack_propagate(0)
mainframe.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

intro = Label(mainframe, text = """Welcome to Linux User & Developers Mega
Microgames Collection.
Select one of the following games to play:
""")
intro.pack(side = TOP)

rpsButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Rock, Paper, Scissors",
                   command = RockPaperScissors.gui)
rpsButton.pack()

hmButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Hangman", command = Hangman.gui)
hmButton.pack()

pdButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Poker Dice", command = PokerDice.start)
pdButton.pack()

exitButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Quit", command = root.destroy)
exitButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the code to Rock, Paper Scissors:

```
from tkinter import *

import random

def gui():

    rock = 1
    paper = 2
    scissors = 3

    names = { rock: "Rock", paper: "Paper", scissors: "Scissors" }
    rules = { rock: scissors, paper: rock, scissors: paper }

    def start():
        while game():
            pass

    def game():
        player = playerChoice.get()
        computer = random.randint(1, 3)
        computerChoice.set(names[computer])
        result(player, computer)

    def result(player, computer):
        newScore = 0
        if player == computer:
            resultSet.set("Tie game.")
        elif rules[player] == computer:
            result.set("Your victory has been assured.")
            newScore = playerScore.get()
            newScore += 1
            playerScore.set(newScore)
        else:
            resultSet.set("The commputer laughs as you realise you have " +
                          "been defeated.")
            newScore = computerScore.get()
            newScore += 1
            computerScore.set(newScore)

    rpsWindow = Toplevel()
    rpsWindow.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")

    playerChoice = IntVar()
    computerChoice = StringVar()
    resultSet = StringVar()
    playerChoice.set(1)
    playerScore = IntVar()
    computerScore = IntVar()

    **rpsFrame = Frame(rpsWindow, padding = '3 3 12 12', width = 300)**
    #this is what is causing the error
    rpsFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
    rpsFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    rpsFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    Label(rpsFrame, text = 'Player').grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)
    Radiobutton(rpsFrame, text = 'Rock', variable = playerChoice,
                value = 1).grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
    Radiobutton(rpsFrame, text = 'Paper', variable = playerChoice,
                value = 2).grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
    Radiobutton(rpsFrame, text = 'Scissors', variable = playerChoice,
                value = 3).grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)

    Label(rpsFrame, text = 'Computer').grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)
    Label(rpsFrame, textvariable = computerChoice).grid(column = 1,
                                                        row = 3, sticky = W)

    Button(rpsFrame, text = "Play", command = start).grid(column = 2, row = 2)

    Label(rpsFrame, text = "Score").grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = W)
    Label(rpsFrame, textvariable = playerScore).grid(column = 1,
                                                     row = 6, sticky = W)

    Label(rpsFrame, text = "Score").grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = W)
    Label(rpsFrame, textvariable = computerScore).grid(column = 3,
                                                       row = 6, sticky = W)

    Label(rpsFrame, textvariable = resultSet).grid(column = 2, row = 7)
```

Here is the Hangman code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

word = 0
wordLength = 0
clue = 0

def gui():
    global word, wordLength, clue
    dictionary = ["..."]
    #I've omitted the words due to length
    word = random.choice(dictionary)
    wordLength = len(word)
    clue = wordLength * ["_"]
    tries = 6

    def hangedman(hangman):
        grphic = ["""..."""]
        #I've omitted the ASCII graphics that go in the list due to length
        graphicSet = graphic[hangman]
        hmGraphic.set(graphicSet)

    def game():
        lettersWrong = incorrectGuess.get()
        letter = guessLetter()
        firstIndex = word.find(letter)
        if firstIndex == -1:
            lettersWrong += 1
            incorrectGuesses.set(lettersWrong)
        else:
            for i in range(wordLength):
                if letter ++ word[i]:
                    clue[i] = letter
        hangedman(lettersWrong)
        clueSet = " ".join(clue)
        wordOutput.set(clueSet)
        if lettersWrong == tries:
            resultText = "Game Over. The word was " + word
            resultSet.set(resultText)
            newScore = computerScore.get()
            newScore += 1
            computerScore.set(newScore)
        if "".join(clue) == word:
            resultText = "You win! The word as " + word

    def guessLetter():
        letter = letterGuess.get()
        letter = letter.strip()
        letter = letter.lower()
        return letter

    def resetGame():
        global word, wordLength, clue
        incorrectGuesses.set(0)
        hangedman(0)
        resultSet.set("")
        letterGuess.set("")
        word = random.choice(dictionary)
        wordLength = len(word)
        clue = wordLength * ["_"]
        newClue = " ".join(clue)
        wordOutput.set(newClue)

    hmWindow = Toplevel()
    hmWindow.title("Hangman")
    incorrectGuesses = IntVar()
    incorrectGuesses.set(0)
    playerScore = IntVar()
    computerScore = IntVar()
    resultSet = StringVar()
    letterGuess = StringVar()
    wordOutput = StringVar()
    hmGraphic = StringVar()

    **hmFrame = Frame(hmWindow, padding = "3 3 12 12", width = 300)**
    #this is what is causing the error
    hmFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, stick = (N, W, E, S))
    hmFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    hmFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    Label(hmFrame, textvariable = hmGraphic).grid(column = 2, row = 1)
    Label(hmFrame, text = "Word").grid(column = 2, row = 2)
    Label(hmFrame, textvariable = wordOutput).grid(column = 2, row = 3)

    Label(hmFrame, text = "Enter a letter").grid(column = 2, row = 4)
    hmEntry = Entry(hmFrame, exportselection = 0,
                    textvariable = letterGuess).grid(column = 2, row = 5)
    hmEntryButton = Button(hmFrame, text = "Guess",
                           command = game).grid(column = 2, row = 10)

    Label(hmFrame, text = "Wins").grid(column = 1, row = 7, sticky = W)
    Label(hmFrame, textvariable = playerScore).grid(column = 1, row = 8,
                                                    sticky = W)
    Label(hmFrame, text = "Losses").grid(column = 3, row = 7, sticky = W)
    Label(hmFrame, textvariable = computerScore).grid(column = 3, row = 8,
                                                      sticky = W)
    Label(hmFrame, textvariable = resultSet).grid(column = 2, row = 9)
    replayButton = Button(hmFrame, text = "Reset",
                          command = resetGame).grid(column = 2, row = 10)
```

Comment: Yes, there is no such `padding` option. Please refer to [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)

Comment: To duplicate this problem you only need three lines of code; you don't need to include your whole program.

Answer (score 8):

There are virtually no differences between tkinter in 2.x vs 3.x, except for the import statements. This is not a 2.x vs 3.x problem.

The `padding` option is only valid for `ttk.Frame`, but you're using `tkinter.Frame`. For the standard tkinter `Frame` widget you have the `padx` and `pady` options.